# Not parabolic falling

Tags: classical-mechanics

Suppose a small mass *m* is launched from height *h* with horizontal initial speed *v0*; if the ground is horizontal, it's easy to calculate the equation of movement (parabolic), because the coordinates of *P* (the vector of weight) are constant (*0* on x-axis and *-mg* on vertical axis).

Now, I suppose the ground is not horizontal, but spherical (say, the earth); the coordinates of weight *P* are now varying with time and are dependent of angle *alpha(t)*...

I dont't understand how to start to find the movement equation of the mass *m*, as I don't know how to calculate *alpha* as a function of time *t* (or maybe it's not the best way to start)

Could you please point me to the solution or give me some directions to do so?

[image: Falling]

Comment: Well, I think there's a certain vector quantity angular momentum that will remain conserved about point (identify that point yourself)! That's the hint I suppose

Comment: Another hint: what happens if you launch it really fast, and what are the equations for that behavior?

Comment: Yet another hint: how could this problem be related to the motion of a satellite around the earth, or to the motion of the earth around the sun?

Comment: $\begin{aligned}x=v\cdot t\\
y=-\dfrac {gt^{2}}{2}+h\\
\tan \left( \alpha \right) =\dfrac {x\left( t\right) }{R+y\left( t\right) }\end{aligned}$

Comment: Eli, that's not true. In your equation `y=0` when `t=sqrt{2h/g}`; that's true when vector `P` remains vertical...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't neglect the curvature of the Earth and the dependence of gravity on distance, you arrive at Kepler's laws. I.e. your trajectory would be an ellipse with Earth's center (assuming the planet is spherical) in one focus, and the other focus being somewhere on the line connecting the Earth center to the starting point of your motion.
This ellipse may intersect the Earth's surface (if the periapsis of your orbit is smaller than Earth's radius), in which case you hit it at some point. Or it won't (if the periapsis is larger than Earth's radius - of course, in case of Earth one also needs to take atmosphere into account, so truly periodic orbits must have periapsis above the radius + atmosphere height), in which case you're in periodic orbit.
You can tell which situation you'll be in by your initial velocity - if it's lower than some critical value, it would intersect the Earth's surface.
Long story short, look up info on orbital motion.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume a constant value of gravitational acceleration the movement equation is the same for all types of ground. If you want to determine the angle you have to switch to polar coordinates, which is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking orbital mechanics.  The full equations are

$$\frac {-GMm}{r^2}=m( \ddot r-r \dot \theta^2)$$
$$0=m(r\ddot \theta+2\dot r \dot \theta)$$

With initial conditions at t=0

$$r=R+h$$
$$\dot r=0$$
$$\theta=0$$
$$\dot \theta=V_0/(R+h)$$